# Exception Value : name 'newsletter' is not defined - python

Tags: python, django

Hi am new to python And Django.

i have just created a new app called `newsletter`

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

**Urls.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [


url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', newsletter.views.home, name='home'),
]
```

When i try to access it in the browser like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsletter` i am getting the error.

```
NameError at /newsletter
name 'newsletter' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsletter
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'newsletter' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/src/trydjango18/urls.py in <module>, line 23
Python Executable:  /home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/src',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/baman/Desktop/trydjango18/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 21 Jun 2015 06:10:08 +0000
```

My folder look like this

[image]

Can someone help me to fix this tnx.

Comment: Have you added your application newsletter in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS section

Comment: ok i added it when i run the server i get this error `ImportError: No module named newsletter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be adding the `newsletter` application to the `INSTALLED_APPS` section in `settings.py`

**Example**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'newsletter',
)
```

This lets the Django project know that there is an application named `newsletter`

Now you need to import `newsletter` to the `urls.py` as

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

#newly added
import newsletter

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', newsletter.views.home, name='home'),
]
```

---

**Note** It is advisable that you add a new `urls.py` for your application, and then include that file within the main file.

That is

the project `url.py` must look like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('newsletter.urls') ), #Changed here
    ]
```

And the url mappings can be written inside the applications, `newsletters` url mapping file, `url.py`

```
# Newly added file in the newsletter directory
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from newsletter import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

Comment: Thank you, but still getting the error `name 'newsletter' is not defined`

Comment: @SathyaBaman You nedd to import newsletter to urls.py. I have edited the answer. Do read the note at the end. It is how it should be done in a proper way than writing it in the main `url.py` file

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Comment: @SathyaBaman You are welcome. I hope you do it in the django way by separating the urls from main `url.py` to applications `url.py`